# Laravel Print with DomPDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

i was trying to print invoice with Laravel using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

I used the following code to convert pdf:

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('print.service_x')->setPaper('a4','portrait');
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

But the style got break...some of the text overlap the table. How do i solve this problem?

[image]
[Style link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkiib.png) is OK...As when i load the page without `pdf` it shows me correct view:

Comment: seems that you are using compound table heading. It not worked correctly...

Comment: thing is dompdf is not perfect, in most cases you have to modify your html and css and make sure you use only the features that are supported "Handles most CSS 2.1 and a few CSS3 properties"

Comment: Create simple `table` structure with simple styles: `<style type="text/css">
 table td, table th{
  border:1px solid black;
 }
</style>` Then it's works! Refer this link: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-generate-pdf-from-html-view-file-and-download-using-dompdfexample.html